# How to add a warning popup when commiting specific files in svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

I am working on a large .NET web project, and I would like to prevent developers on the team submitting `.config`-files by mistake. The solution I would like to have is some sort of popup as a warning saying *"Are you sure you want to commit these files?"* when someone is trying to commit `.config`-files. It should be legal to do so, but with a warning first.

We are using Apache Subversion setup with VisualSVN Server and TortoiseSVN as svn gui client.

Is there any possibility to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use a [pre-commit hook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.ref.reposhooks.pre-commit.html) script to block commits for some files unless a specific hashtag is included in the log message.

Output from the script is displayed in the Tortoise commit dialog, explaining why the commit was blocked and what hashtag to add if the developer is sure they meant to commit those files.

Answer (score 0):

I could guess that those config files are already in the version control and commited with some necessary changes , and you don't want that file to be committed again with lack of caution

To achieve this you have to make some changes in developers tortoise svn by adding

```
 svn changelist ignore-on-commit file-name
```

TortoiseSVN (a Windows GUI client) has provision for "ignore-on-commit", but command line svn does not.

So you can instruct your developers to add the config file changelist and in case if some responsible person wants to commit the new configuration file he can do it from command line  manually instead of using tortoise SVN GUI

You can add a file to ignore-on-commit list from context menu also , I think latest version of tortoise svn has that feature .

Comment: Yes you can do this by adding it to the ignore-on-commit list, but then again, everybody has to remember to add the files to this list. When we have many projects, this is not a great solution. (This is the way we are doing it now).

Comment: you would have specified your currently used solution and elaborate the problem what you are facing , right now with this solution ,I agree this may not be a  great solution for this great question .

Comment: @andreasnico  you have asked " Is there any possibility to accomplish this? "

Comment: well I was trying to elaborate with my comment so I could get the solution I was looking for.